# WebView and Toolbar wont align

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I have a WebView and Toolbar that do not align either on the 4" simulator or 3.5 inch. I have added constraints but either the Toolbar shows and the WebView drops under my tab bar or the WebView screen is showing but no Toolbar.

Solved: I just reset to suggested constraints and it fixed the issue. 
Im sorry if I didn't allow anyone a chance to answer. Im not sure exactly what to do with a question if its not been answered Im new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you possible post an image of the problem? Thanks

Comment: I just reset to suggested constraints and it fixed the issue. Im sorry if I didn't allow anyone a chance to answer. Im not sure exactly what to do with a question if its not been answered Im new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I just reset to suggested constraints and it fixed the issue. Im sorry if I didn't allow anyone a chance to answer. Im not sure exactly what to do with a question if its not been answered Im new to stackoverflow.